# Как вернуть значение в NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

Как я могу сделать что-нибудь наподобие этого?

```
function getAll() {
  const sql = `SELECT * FROM ${table};`;
  const query = db.query(sql, (err, rows) => {
    if (err) {
      req.status(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).send(INTERNAL_ERROR_MSG);
    }
    else {
      return rows;
    }
  });
}

function someFunc() {
  const rows = getAll(); // undefined
}
```

Comment: Это SO на русском

Comment: Спасибо, @Mr. Brightside!

Comment: Спасибо, @Alexey Ten!